# Simple form to edit only one field of model in Spring MVC

Tags: forms, spring-mvc

What is the best way to change data of, for example, User?
I got lots of properties like 'username', 'city', 'phone' and when I want to edit just one field ('password'), I have to do this:

```
<form:form action="editUser.htm?id=${user.id}" commandname="user">
    <form:hidden path='username' />
    <form:hidden path='city' />
    <form:hidden path='phone' />
    <form:input path='password' />

....
```

In my controller action is defined:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/editUser.htm", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView ordertypeedit(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, 
        BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request)throws Exception{
        userTypeValidator.validate(orderType, result);
        if(result.hasErrors()){
        (...)
        return new ModelAndView(...);
        }
        orderTypeDAO.update(orderType);
        return new ModelAndView(...);
```

I don't like to set all the  to my action form... If I miss it, it shows error 'column 'username' cannot be null".

Answer (score 4):

It depends if your properties are validated or mandatory on that form:

If not, then you don't need to submit them with your form:

```
<form:form action="editUser.htm?id=${user.id}" commandname="user">
    <form:input path='password' />
```

and in your controller you will get user object with only user parameter.

Alternative way is to pass regular (not Spring MVC) form and create inside user object with only id and password properties.

Answer (score 1):

you can use simple (without spring tags) form with one input and get it in controller using @RequestParam